# Foundation 6 CSS Checkbox Styling

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Currently trying to make custom CSS Checkbox's with existing CSS code.

```css
.nk-btn-color-dark-5 {
  background-color: #293139;
  border-color: #101215;
  border-style: solid;
}

.nk-btn-color-dark-5:hover,
.nk-btn-color-dark-5.hover {
  background-color: #3b4550;
  border-color: #4a5665;
}

.nk-btn-color-dark-5:active,
.nk-btn-color-dark-5.active {
  background-color: #4a5665;
  border-color: #59687a;
}

.nk-btn-color-dark-5.nk-btn-outline {
  color: #293139;
}

.nk-btn-color-dark-5.nk-btn-outline:hover,
.nk-btn-color-dark-5.nk-btn-outline.hover {
  color: #14171b;
}

.nk-btn-color-dark-5.nk-btn-outline:active {
  color: black;
}

.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7.nk-btn-color-white:hover,
.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7.nk-btn-color-white.hover,
.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7.nk-btn-color-white:active,
.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7.nk-btn-color-white.active {
  color: #fff;
}

.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7:hover,
.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7.hover {
  background-color: #FFD700;
  border-color: #a5102c;
}

.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7:active,
.nk-btn-hover-main-7.active {
  background-color: #FFD700;
  border-color: #a5102c;
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="prod" value="1">
<label class="nk-btn nk-btn-rounded nk-btn-color-dark-5 nk-btn-hover-color-main-7" for="checkbox1">Add to Cart</label>
```

Current CSS for said button.
And HTML, I am unable to figure out how to make it work. I've tried as much as i know, Using this as a guidance.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJVgQm

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you got stuck with? This works nearly as the linked example, only the input is not hidden. Please describe the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the checkbox to be invisible and affect the styling of it's sibling label, you're missing just two things:

`input:checked + label` targets the label that's next to a checkbox with [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

`#checkbox1{display: none;}` hides your checkbox.

```css
#checkbox1{display: none;}

.nk-btn-color-dark-5 {
  background-color: #293139;
  border-color: #101215;
  border-style: solid;
}

.nk-btn-color-dark-5:hover,
.nk-btn-color-dark-5.hover {
  background-color: #3b4550;
  border-color: #4a5665;
}

.nk-btn-color-dark-5:active,
.nk-btn-color-dark-5.active {
  background-color: #4a5665;
  border-color: #59687a;
}

.nk-btn-color-dark-5.nk-btn-outline {
  color: #293139;
}

.nk-btn-color-dark-5.nk-btn-outline:hover,
.nk-btn-color-dark-5.nk-btn-outline.hover {
  color: #14171b;
}

input:checked + label,
.nk-btn-color-dark-5.nk-btn-outline:active {
  color: black;
}

.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7.nk-btn-color-white:hover,
.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7.nk-btn-color-white.hover,
.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7.nk-btn-color-white:active,
.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7.nk-btn-color-white.active {
  color: #fff;
}

.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7:hover,
.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7.hover {
  background-color: #FFD700;
  border-color: #a5102c;
}

input:checked + label,
.nk-btn-hover-color-main-7:active,
.nk-btn-hover-main-7.active {
  background-color: #FFD700;
  border-color: #a5102c;
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="prod" value="1">
<label class="nk-btn nk-btn-rounded nk-btn-color-dark-5 nk-btn-hover-color-main-7" for="checkbox1">Add to Cart</label>
```

Comment: I definitely was doing this! I appreciate this alot, I just had Input after the div! Thank you very much